# A real time character-by-character texting app?

Tags: plain-text, communication, health, real-time, text

This is the task I want to accomplish. I want to try a kind of therapy where the therapist reads my thoughts over text in real time and I read her thoughts over text in real time. This is accomplished via real time, character-by-character texting. In normal texting, the entire message is sent at once. This kind of texting is real time, so the therapist sees each individual character as I type it. I originally thought of using a Google Doc but I want it to automatically scroll down as we type, and also a Google Doc isn't quiet real time. I thought of rolling my own solution by opening up two terminals or two sets of terminals (one incoming and one outgoing) and sending each individual character in real time over UDP but terminals are hard for non-programmers such as therapists to read and I'm sure someone has already created some sort of an app for this. Can someone please find me one? I would prefer mobile but desktop or web works too.

**Edit**: Also the therapist and I will be in the same building on the same Wi-Fi network so if it could let me plug in a local IP address, like in the browser address bar, that would be a plus because then we wouldn't have the lag of being over the public internet.